# Compare two lists of dictionaries by key and return repetitions

Tags: sorting, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dictionaries with the same keys, but different values:

```
dic1 = {'popped': ['question', '30', 'balloon', '18', 'zit', '10', 'popcorn', '6', 'pimple', '6', 'cherry', '5'],
'planted': ['tree', '30', 'seed', '28', 'flower', '20', 'plant', '7', 'bomb', '4', 'garden', '2'],
'distilled ': ['water', '45', 'vodka', '9', 'vinegar', '7', 'beer', '6', 'alcohol', '5', 'whiskey', '5'] }
```

and

```
dic2 = {'popped ': ['question', '30', 'balloon', '18', 'zit', '10', 'popcorn', '6', 'pimple', '6'] 
'planted ': ['flower', '28', 'tree', '18', 'seed', '9', 'vegetable', '4', 'bush', '3', 'grass', '3'], 'aaron distilled  ': ['water', '14', 'vinegar', '9', 'wine', '8', 'alcohol', '8']}
```

I want to compare the two of them to find what values are repeated in both, so that my outcome would be something like:

```
dic3 = {'popped ': ['balloon', 'question', 'popcorn'], 
'planted ': ['flower', 'tree', 'seed'], 
'distilled  ': ['water', 'vinegar','alcohol']}
```

I tried some different things, but I am no close to succeed. Do you have any suggestions on each direction to take? I thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic3=dict()

    for key, val in dic1.items():
        val2=dic2[key]

        val3=set(val).intersection(set(val2))
        dic3[key]=val3
```